# How can I use a '#' character in a git command?

Tags: vim, git, github, vim-plugins, bitbucket.org

I'm trying to close an issue on Bitbucket from a commit message through fugitive.vim's Gcommit command:

`:Gcommit -m "Fixes #1"`

When I check the commit message, `#1` has been replaced with `index.html` (the file I am working on), so the commit message looks like this:

```
Fixes index.html
```

This isn't the behavior I'm looking for. **When using fugitive.vim, how can I close a Bitbucket or GitHub issue with :Gcommit?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the command line, `#1` is replaced by the name of buffer number 1.

I don't use fugitive so I can't test it myself but you could try to escape the `#` with a backslash as explained in `:h cmdline-special`:

```
:Gcommit -m "Fixes \#1"
```